# Using numpy.ndarray.ndim(arr) directly get the number of dimensions

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Can i directly use the command numpy.ndarray.ndim(arr) to get the no. of dimensions for an array ?? without importing numpy. Is it possible ??

Comment: What is `arr`?  If it's a numpy array, then you just have already imported numpy.

Comment: Here (arr) is an array created using the  Standard Python Library class array.array

Comment: then numpy functions don't apply.

Answer (score 1):

no,
but you can use the array attribute `arr.ndim` to get it. [ndarray.ndim](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.ndim.html)

Answer (score 0):

No, without importing a module you can't use anything defined in that module.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [954]: import array                                                                                 
In [955]: a = array.array('i')                                                                         
In [956]: a.fromlist([1,2,3])                                                                          
In [957]: a                                                                                            
Out[957]: array('i', [1, 2, 3])
In [958]: len(a)                                                                                       
Out[958]: 3
```

Like a list, `a` has a `len`.  It does not have a `ndim`:

```
In [959]: a.ndim                                                                                       
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-959-2cb81154a11f> in <module>
----> 1 a.ndim

AttributeError: 'array.array' object has no attribute 'ndim'
```

`ndim` is a property of a `numpy.ndarray`.  It's not relevant to `list` or to `array`.  If given one of thosr, `np.ndim` first converts it `np.asarray(a)`:

```
In [960]: np.ndim(a)                                                                                   
Out[960]: 1                            # always 1
In [961]: np.ndim([1,2,3])                                                                             
Out[961]: 1
```

While lists can be nested, `array.array` has to contain a predefined element type, as documented.  It does not have a general object type, so will always be 1 dimensional.